# NGINX try_files works for all but one url

Tags: nginx, configuration-files

I have a simple dashboard for my site.  Here is the directive:

```
location /dashboard {
    try_files $uri /dashboard/index.php;
}
```

It works for all items after /dashboard.  For example, /users or /pages - all CRUD operations work as expected.

The index.php file at /dashboard is my "controller".  It parses the url and includes and runs scripts from there.

For example:  **/dashboard/group/edit/123456**  works as expected and I get the edit page for group number 123456.

But when I post from that page to /dashboard/group/update, it serves **/dashboard/group/index.php**

So, in the first example, The edit page is loaded and the url at the top of the screen does not change.

In the second example, NGINX is CHANGING the url so my script cannot get the url parts to do the job.

I thought it may have something to do with POST, but I have other forms that use POST without issue.

In addition, or possibly a clue, try_files is returning /dashboard/**group**/index.php while the directive should return /dashboard/index.php.

Is there another NGINX file that could have so old code in it that is overwriting this domain's  config?

I've been at this a few hours and have run out of ideas.  Any thoughts?

*** One More Clue ***

When I **BROWSE** to /dashboard/group/update, NGINX shows the page as expected.  It is only when I **POST** to that page that NGNIX sends me to /dashboard/**group**/index.php.

Again, at the very least, it should be sending me to /dashboard/index.php and NOT /dashboard/**group**/index.php.

Comment: First glance it looks like the behavior might be caused by other parts of your configuration. Eliminate the issue by commenting everything else then bring it back block by block

Comment: Maybe it’s your application doing a redirect here? Use a client like `curl -is -XPOST http://..` or Postman to avoid issues with multiple redirects giving wrong clues, browser cache etc while debugging the issue

Answer (score 0):

You not send all after `/dashboard` try this:

```
location /dashboard {
    try_files $uri /dashboard/index.php?$uri&$args;
}
```

OR

```
location /dashboard {
    try_files $uri /dashboard/index.php?$query_string;
}
```

Nginx docs: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files

Comment: Thanks for the reply.   I am POSTing the form data so there are no additional URL params.

Comment: You writed "In the second example, NGINX is CHANGING the url so my script cannot get the url parts to do the job.". This answer can solve this.

Comment: To be clear, I did try this - I tried GET vs POST and got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
location /dashboard {
    try_files $uri /dashboard/index.php;
}
```

Try

```
location /dashboard {
    index index.php; #adding this may work alone
    try_files $uri /dashboard/index.php?$uri;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.   Still not working.   I do not think NGINX is using this location directive because it would/should return /dashboard/index.php at the very least.  Instead it is returning /dashboard/group/index.php

Comment: Have you made sure to test the config using sudo nginx -t and then restarting or reloading nginx? Nginx doesn't automatically update its configs until you tell it to or restart it.

Comment: Yes, every time I make a change, nginx -t and restart

Answer (score 0):

I have concluded that I have a cache problem.   The location directive works on all items that I have not yet accessed.

So, my configuration - as described - works as it should.

I just have to figure out how to clear my cache ( which in NOT set up in NGINX that I can see!)

Thank you all who helped!